# Обратный шаг в режиме отладки

Tags: отладка, visual-basic

Visual Studio. Basic. В режиме отладки мной добавлены точки останова. Перемещаюсь по f11. Заметил некорректность в коде, хочу вернуться на шаг назад. Есть обратное действие по отношению к f11? Есть ли какие-либо другие способы возвращения к предыдущей итерации в коде без перезапуска программы?
Прошу простить если плохо выражаю свои мысли и объясняю не доходчиво. Учусь. Заранее спасибо за уделенное время.

Comment: Выражаете мысли нормально. В отладчике IntelliJ-IDEA есть кнопка "Drop frame". Надеюсь, что аналогичная кнопка есть в Visual Studio.

Comment: @Igor, мысли он как раз нормально выразил, но он хочет немного не перезапуск фрейма.

Comment: @Qwertiy Значит, я его все-таки неправильно понял :).

Comment: @Igor, кстати, перезапуск фрейма ведь тоже побочные эффекты не откатывает?

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет. Стараемся писать функции без побочных эффектов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перетащи жёлтую стрелочку, указывающую на исполняемую инструкцию, на ту строку, которая тебя интересует. Обращаю внимание, что это не отмена шага, т. е. если были выполнены операции, имеющие побочные эффекты, то эти эффекты сохранятся. Если их надо (и можно) устранить, то можно воспользоваться Immediate Pane, выполнив в ней соответствующий код; либо же, если речь идёт о изменении значений простых переменных, просто поменять их значение в окне, появляющемся при наведении мышки на переменную, или в Watch.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Вы мне очень помогли. Все методы, что вы описали, я ранее не знал, как и о "побочных эффектах". Это во множество раз упрощает процесс отладки.